# Using git desktop I committed my changes and pressed sync. There were merge errors and my local files got changed a lot. How to undo changes?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally synced when I shouldn't have done and changed a lot of my local files how do I undo this sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer assumes that a) you committed all your valuable work already, and b) you don't want anything which came in from the recent merge ("sync"), from the remote branch.  Assuming both of these are true, you can just do a hard reset to the current HEAD of your branch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

In case you ever end up in a similar situation where you *don't* want to nuke your entire working directory (and maybe stage as well, if you've staged anything), you can use the following command to checkout an individual file from the HEAD:

```
git checkout -- path/to/some/file.ext
```

Comment: it won't let me accept your answer yet but omg I love you. It worked perfectly and even undid the directory changes that were made.